# How to customize view order module frontend customers

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento2

I have a situation where I need to slice the Tax into two parts if the customer belongs to the certain provenance. see image

[image]

The URL I see is : example.com/sales/order/view/order_id/10/

Now I want to customize it as per my requirement but I do not have any idea how to override core module and which file should I change to.

Any help will be appreciated greatly.

Many thanks

Comment: Whats your Magento version? Tags are unclear ...

Comment: @sv3n magento v 2.0